# Swift populate UITableView before App is loaded

Tags: swift, uitableview

Is there any way to load data into UITableView before App is loaded?

1. Is it possible?
2. Is it a good practice?

P.S. I want to do this because when tab with TableView is clicked first time -> Data loading takes about 1-2 sec

Comment: `UITableView` is a view and it is not possible to populate a view before it's loaded.

Comment: so can I prepare data for UITableView before app is loaded?

Comment: depends on what data is it, where you are getting it from and how much there is. there isn't enough information in your question for us to answer effectively

Comment: sorry for lack of information in my question, data is from realm database, there are not so much rows

Comment: You can't do anything before the app is loaded.  What would be executing?  If your data takes a long(ish) time to load then you should have the UI show that it is processing (some kind of activity indicator) and then once finished show the actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access and populate *any view* before it is loaded, and it does so only once the whole application has been loaded. A `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIView`, so the same applies in this case.

> "I want to do this because when tab with TableView is clicked first time -> Data loading takes about 1-2 sec."

If you retrieve your data from an external online database, you can load your data when the app launches, inside:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
```

And later you can pass your data to your table view in any effective way, such that it only takes time to pass the data, and not to retrieve it. But all this depends on what kind and what amount of data you are retrieving.